# How To Increment Number At End of String For Cell Range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write code to increment a number at the end of a string.  I'd like to take the string "FS_CAP_1_001" in column H, and increment the string down the rows so it increments as "FS_CAP_1_002", "FS_CAP_1_003", "FS_CAP_1_004", etc.  However, I only want to do this if the string starts with "FS_CAP_1_".

I've written some code below, but I can't even Step Into the function when I'm compiling the project to debug it.

I have read the question "Increment number at end of string" on this site, as well as a few other related questions, and I can't seem to put the code together correctly.  I'm a beginner with VBA, and it's been at least a year since I've written any code with it.

```
Function NumberIncrement_CapCode_Tier1_Lvl1(ByVal txt As String) As String

With Worksheets("PD Code Structure")

Dim i As Integer
Dim myVal As Integer
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Worksheets("PD Code Structure").Range(Cells(i, 8))
txt = cell.Value

myVal = Val(Split(txt, "_")(1)) + 1

NumberIncrement_CapCode_Tier1_Lvl1 = Split(txt, "_")(0) & "_" & Format(myVal, "000")

Next cell

End With

End Function
```

My expected result is for each row in column "H", where the string starts with "FS_CAP_1_", that the subsequent rows will increment to show "FS_CAP_1_002", "FS_CAP_1_003", "FS_CAP_1_004", etc.

I can't even Step Into the function when I'm compiling the project to debug it.

Comment: You can do this with a formula, do you need VBA?

Comment: Hi Ben, I'll be doing this to multiple columns in my spreadsheet, as well as concatenating two cells together, and I thought VBA would be a quicker way to get it done.  The spreadsheet is pretty large.

Comment: If you're not going to use the formula, per Ben's suggestion, you just want `if instr(cell.value,"fs_cap_1_") then cell.value = cell.value & Format(i,"000") // i=i+1`, right?

Comment: Hi Cyril, I just tried your code: `Sub NumberIncrement()

With Worksheets("PD Code Structure")

Dim i As Integer
Dim cell As Range
i = i + 1

If InStr(cell.Value, "FS_CAP_1_") Then
cell.Value = cell.Value & Format(i, "000")

End If
End With
End Sub`   and I got the error "Object variable or with block variable not set".

Comment: That's because you have not `Set cell = ...` or not used it in a loop, `For Each cell In...`

Answer (score 0):

A Regular Expression pattern can use the `$` as a code to find the pattern when it occurs at the end of a string.

If the `FS_CAP_1_` portion is somewhat dynamic you might want to use something that only deals with the numbers at the end of the string.

```
Function myIncrement(str As String, _
                     Optional z As Integer = 3) As String
    Dim rgx As Object, inc1 As String

    Set rgx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With rgx

        .Pattern = Format(z, "\[\0\-9\]{0}$")

        If .test(str) Then

            inc1 = .Execute(str)(0)

            myIncrement = Left(str, Len(str) - z) & Format(CLng(inc1) + 1, String(z, "0"))

        End If

    End With

End Function
```

In A3 you would use it by referencing FS_CAP_1_001 in A2.

```
=myIncrement(A2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working correctly with the following code:

```
Sub NumberIncrement()

With Worksheets("PD Code Structure")
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cell As Range
    i = 1

    For Each cell In .Range("H2: H1006")

      If InStr(cell.Value, "FS_CAP_1_") Then
        cell.Value = cell.Value & Format(i, "000")
        i = i + 1
      End If

    Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Thank you everyone for your help!